# How to ignore Decimal

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have tried to do this - Making any float value to int value. What I tried to achieve is make it 2.00-2.99 goes to 2.

Note: Im not trying to do Approximation (lower than 2.49 goes to 2, and those 2.50+ goes to 3).

I have done this so far

```
public int RemoveDecimal(float value)
{
    string TempText = (string)value;
    TempText.Remove(IndexOf('.'));
    return int.parse(TempText);
}
```

But this will get an error when the float value ends with .00

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: How do you want to treat negative values? Towards `0`, towards `-inf`, or are they invalid?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but it's possible that `decimal` fits your requirements better than `float`/`double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx) is the function you need.

It:

> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number.

Example:

```
var val = Math.Floor(value);
```

Or, you could simply cast to an integer - this will simply ignore the decimal portion, so long as the range of the `decimal` is within the range of an `int` (otherwise you will get an exception):

```
int noDecimals = (int)value;
```

Comment: Why are you converting from float to decimal first?

Comment: @MrLister - Didn't notice the value passed in to the function was a `float` to begin with. Just saw the string first...

Comment: Because input value is string. @ Mr Lister

Comment: @MdKamruzzamanPallob - No it isn't. The OP is converting a `float` to a `string` and trying to work with that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Cast to `int` I presume? That will fail if the value is outside the range for an `int`. `Math.Floor` is definitely the safest way here.

Comment: @MrLister: Well, the OP's method returns `int` - so I was making the assumption that the OP needed an `int` value. Looks like I hadn't read the question quite correctly though, if the aim is to get a string. But by the time it's outside the range of `int`, the results may end up being quite unexpected...

Comment: since `value` is `float`, `Math.Floor(value)` won't compile.

Comment: @MrLister Floor does not what the OP said he wants for negative values. But not sure what he actually wants in that case.

Comment: @RayCheng - There is an implicit conversion between `float` and `double`. It will work just fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right about the OP restricting himself to int ranges in his function. But he did say "any float value"! And, assuming your basic floating point implementation, the results of calculations on larger values are all predictable. For instance, you can store 2^32 in a float (with no loss of precision), and if you `Math.Floor` that, the result is 2^32 too.

Comment: how about the range? range for float is much bigger than int, even int64.

Comment: @RayCheng - Yes, this has been discussed in the comments already. And I did mention that in my answer.

Comment: @MrLister: You can't store 2^32-1 in a float with no loss of precision though... it may be *predictable*, but that doesn't mean it's what people would predict :) (Obviously the problem isn't really at the point of the range of `int` - the precision goes below the integer level much earlier than that.)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the solutions. I got it worked now. By the way I think I am not dealing with anything that is out of int range, but thanks for the precautions.

Comment: @JonSkeet That wasn't my point. The OP said "any float value", which to me means "anything that you can store in a float". And that includes values outside the range of an `int`, even a `long int`. That's all. The example code in the question was what the OP _tried_, not what the OP _needed_.

Comment: without properly handling the range, `float.MaxValue` will always crash (most of float values).

Comment: @MrLister: Sure. I'm just pointing out that if the OP is unaware of `Math.Floor`, they may well find that any place that an `int` cast would fail, the OP will quite possibly not be getting the results that they expect anyway.

Comment: @RayCheng - Yes, this has been mentioned. Both in comments and in the answer.

Comment: since OP said out of range is not a problem. please make an edit to your post then i can un-cast downvote.

Answer (score 0):

you can't always convert a `float` to an `int` because most of the values in `float` are out of [range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for `int`. you should return a string.

the following will do just that.

```
public string RemoveDecimal(float value)
{
    string TempText = value.ToString("#");
    return TempText;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply casting a floating point number to int does what you want.

```
i = (int)myFloat;
```

It truncates the fractional digits, i.e. it always goes in the direction of `0`.

```
(int)2    ==  2
(int)1.9  ==  1
(int)-1.5 == -1
```

This will obviously not work correctly if the result is outside the valid range of `int`. If you want to achieve the same thing, but with a floating point number as result, [`Math.Truncate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx) is what you need.

Comment: Like I said in my comment to Jon, casting to `int` will fail if the input is outside the range for an `int`.

Comment: @MrLister the OP has a function is a `float`->`int` signature, so I assume he wants an `int` as result. But I've added something for floating points too.

Comment: The OP did say "any float value" in the text of the question. The example function was just an example, and it didn't work anyway.